# Matlab R2015b - unwanted colors on errorbar()

Tags: matlab, graphics, properties, matlab-figure, errorbar

A minimum working example:

```
x = [1 2 3]
y = [1 2 3]
e = [1 1 1]
eb = errorbar(x,y,e)
```

This code will generate a figure like this:
[image: output code from MWE]

Notice the green and red coloring of some of the errorbar extensions.  Even if `eb.Color = 'k'` is run, or any other code to change the color to black, this coloring remains.

There are many examples on the internet that involve getting the children of `eb` and setting the color of the second child to black, but in R2015b the errorbarseries class has no children.

What is up with this?  I do not understand why matlab has elected to add color to the plot and it seems impossible to remove it.

edit:

Using the `painters` renderer does produce black errorbars so it appears to be a bug in the default renderer.  How do I submit this as a bug report to Mathworks?

Comment: Which OS is this? On my Mac I get error bars in the same blue as the data line. His is with the default OpenGL renderer.

Comment: @zeeMonkeez this is on Windows.

Comment: You can search for and file bug reports [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/?s_tid=srchtitle)

Comment: Doesn't happen on 2016a in windows.